# Chrome clearing login information on start up

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I start chrome I have to re-login to all sites such as stackoverflow. This was done automatically up until a few days ago. I could navigate to stackoverflow and not have to re-login, is there a setting in chrome to fix this ?

Comment: Do you run any memory cleaner? If yes then try to find out the option to not xlear the cookies. Also chexk this option under chrome too.